# django server showing this error in signing up

Tags: django-views, django-templates

Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/Signup
Using the URLconf defined in loginsys.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
login/
The current path, Signup, didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

---

```
`url.py page

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import Home,Signup,Signin,Signout

urlpatterns = [
    path('Home/', Home, name='Home'),
    path('Signup/',Signup,name='Signup'),
    path('Signin/',Signin,name='Signin'),
    path('Signout/',Signout,name='Signout'),
]
`
------------------------
  

    views.py
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages

def Home(request):
    return render(request,'index.html')

def Signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        
    #   username = request.POST.get("username")
        username =request.POST["username"]
        fname = request.POST["fname"]
        lname = request.POST["lname"]
        email = request.POST["email"]
        pass1 = request.POST["pass2"]
        pass2 = request.POST["pass2"]

        my_user=User.objects.create(username,email,pass1)
        my_user.first_name=fname
        my_user.last_name=lname

        my_user.save()

        messages.success(request,"Your account has been successfully created")
        return redirect("Signin")
    else:    
        return render(request,"Signup.html")

def Signin(request):
    return render(request,"Signin.html")

def Signout(request):
    pass

----------------------------------------
Signup.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Signup</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Sign Up</h1>

    <form action="{% url 'Signup' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

        <label for="">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="create a username(only letters and numbers)" required>
        <br>

        <label for="">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="enter yoour Fisrt name" required>
        <br>

        <label for="">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="enter your Last name" required>
        <br>

        <label for="">Email Address</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="enter your Email Address" required>
        <br>

        <label for="">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="pass1" name="pass1" placeholder="enter Password" required>
        <br>

        <label for="">Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="pass2" name="pass2" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
        <br>

        <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

I am expecting a success message should be displayed on the screen and signup will work properly.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have defined an app-level `urls.py` file. You need to include this in your main `urls.py` file.
In `loginsys.urls`, add the following:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
   # leave your url paths as they are
  path("any-name/", include("the_name_of_your_app.urls"),
]
```

Then when you go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/any-name/`, your urls will work.